# Trying to find specific words in textArea

Tags: java, string, swing, character, jtextarea

So what I am trying to do here is to get the text from the JTextArea ta by using the method String code = ta.getText(); ta is located in the class TextIDE and is declared as public static JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();

However, after that I have retrieved the text that is inputted by the user I want to make it into a char array, so I use the method code.toCharrArray(); After that in the method compileText I use the for-statement to look for the letter 'p' and if it is found I call the method p() and I send in where the counter i was and the actual character array, so I can continue my search for the letter 'r' and I do this till the class finds the word print. Whenever it does, It should append another JTextArea which works like a console, located in a class called Listener, so I use Listener.c.jt1.append(s); whereas s is equal to whatever comes after print up until the point where it finds a semicolon ';'.

But it doesn't work, I get no error, so I presume there is a logical error here...
Thanks for any help!! :)

```
public class Compiler { 

    String code = TextIDE.ta.getText(); //Gets the text that was inputted by the user

    public Compiler(){ //Constructor

        if(!(code.endsWith("programEnd"))){
            Listener.c.jt2.append("Error - Code must end with line: programEnd on the last line");
        }else{
            compileText(code, 0);
        }
    }

    public void compileText(String code, int start){ //Starts the compiling
        char[] codeArray =  code.toCharArray();
        System.out.println(codeArray.length);

        for(int i = start; i < codeArray.length; i++){ //Looks for character 'p'
            switch(codeArray[i]){
                case 'p':   p(codeArray, ++i);
                            System.out.println("p");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void p(char[] codeArray, int start){
        for(int i = start; i < codeArray.length; i++){
            switch(codeArray[i]){
                case 'r':   r(codeArray, ++i);
                            System.out.println("r");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void r(char[] codeArray, int start){
        for(int i = start; i < codeArray.length; i++){
            switch(codeArray[i]){
                case 'i':   i(codeArray, ++i);
                            System.out.println("i");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void i(char[] codeArray, int start){
        for(int i = start; i < codeArray.length; i++){
            switch(codeArray[i]){
                case 'n': n(codeArray, ++i);
                            System.out.println("n");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void n(char[] codeArray, int start){
        for(int i = start; i < codeArray.length; i++){
            switch(codeArray[i]){
                case 't': t(codeArray, ++i);
                            System.out.println("t");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void t(char[] codeArray, int start){
            String s = "";
            for(int i = start; i < codeArray.length; i++){
                if(!(codeArray[i] == ';')){
                    s += codeArray[i];
                }else{
                    Listener.c.jt1.append(s);
                    compileText(code, ++i);
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: you cant awaiting some help from this desciption, nor from code, you have to provide more details than that, for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: use set/getDocument (model for JTextComponents)

Comment: read Oracle tutorials about JTextComponents for working code example about How to search ....

Comment: I want to find the word print in a char array, how do i do that? and then continue looking for maybe another word just as like it?

Comment: I want to find the word print in a char array because indexof(str) will only return me the first word that starts with print, I want all of them. For example in the text "asdhfuhadsufh print adhfuhadfuj print" there are two variables that is equal to "print"! :)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to find the word print in a char array, how do i do that?

Why are you using a character array? You can just search the text String:

```
String text = textArea.getText();
System.out.println( text.indexof( "print" );
```